# Oracle Sql developer throwing error message : Internal Error: Fetch error message failed! Vendor code 17001

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have recently moved from TCP to TCPS Connection. I can confirm that all my connection parameters are right and properly set. tnsnames.ora and sqlnet.ora is under oracle_home/network/admin folder.

I am trying to connect and getting below error message:
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Internal Error: Fetch error message failed!

Vendor code 17001

Looking for suggestions to fix issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the Oracle Client "bin" directory (e.g. $ORACLE_HOME/bin) is in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: I corrected my oracle_home under system environment variables to C:\Oracle\WINDOWS.X64_193000_client_home and it solved problem.Thank you pmdba.

Just adding a note that i never set oracle_home before so i assume it was set incorrectly by default.

Comment: the ORACLE_HOME var needs to be set too, I think.